# How to redirect my WordPress website to subdomain?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

My WordPress website is currently under maintenance. and I do not want the world to know about it. So I try to pass on to my website subdomain. redirect process that I do is edit in `.htaccess.` but, the problem occurs that I can not see a preview on my WordPress admin panel. There anything you can help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pretty dirty solution that would do the trick. Use this only for temporary purposes. Place this in your themes functions.php (replace the example.com):

```
if( !is_user_logged_in() AND !in_array( $GLOBALS['pagenow'], array( 'wp-login.php' ) ) ):

    header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
    exit;

endif;
```

Then all not logged users are redirected. Probably you have to change these conditions for your needs.

Access the login with

```
www.example.com/wp-login.php
```

instead of

```
www.example.com/wp-admin
```